# Correctly finding numbers in a string?

Tags: c++, string, vector

I'm trying to read characters (numbers) from a string, and then passing them as integers in a vector. Currently something like this:

```
int p;
std::string line = "1111222111"
std::vector<int> vec;
for(int i = 0; i < str.size(); i++)
{
    if(line.find('0', static_cast<std::size_t>(i)) != line.npos)
        p = 0;

    else if(line.find('1', static_cast<std::size_t>(i)) != line.npos)
        p = 1;

    else if(line.find('2', static_cast<std::size_t>(i)) != line.npos)
        p = 2;

    vec.push_back(p);
}
```

When doing this, the vector ends only with 0's. Keep in mind that this is **not** the actual code, just a vague representation of the part where I have my problem. I think I must be doing something wrong in the line.find stuff, but I don't really know any other way to use it (not that I actually know how to really use it...). Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: Are you talking about digits or numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of the [`isdigit`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isdigit/) function to determine if the character is a digit. If so, you can make use of the fact that ASCII orders the digits adjacent.

You can thus solve the problem with the following code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < str.size(); i++) {
    int c = str[i]-'0';
    if(c >= 0 && c <= 9) {
        vec.push_back(c);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  std::vector<int> ans;
  const std::string str = "1234";
  for (int i = 0; i < str.size(); ++i) {
    if ('0' <= str[i] && str[i] <= '9')
      ans.push_back(str[i] - '0');
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should instead of this :

```
for(int i = 0; i < str.size(); i++)
```

have this:

```
 for(int i = 0; i < line.size(); i++)
```

`str` is not defined in your example. I think you meant `line`.

Comment: It was an error of the example, sorry. This does not happen in the actual code